# iPhone Security When Showing Pics

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

Is there a way to keep my iPhone 5 secure when passing it around to show photos?

Yes, even in 2016 some people still behave like they did in High School:  you pass over your phone so they can see a couple of pics and they sift thru your other pics or worse, they start snooping thru other apps.

Perhaps there is a photo app into which I could place selected pics - AND that doesn't allow access outside of the one app.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem (the checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use Guided Access

- Open Settings.app -> General -> Accessibility -> Guided Access (On)
- Open your Photos app and choose the album you want to show your friends.
- Triple-click the side lock button (or home button, if applicable).
- Select Guided Access if menu appears
- Choose to deactivate certain areas of the touch screen to prevent them from accessing navigation.
- Set a password when prompted
- Start guided access and hand your phone around.

To End:

- Triple-click side button
- Tap Guided Access on menu if prompted
- Enter Password
- Select "End"

*Tips*: Restarting your phone will circumvent Guided Access so you will want to have a password on your phone. On iOS 9 you can swipe down on a photo to go back to the album view. To take care of this, make sure that you have only the photos that you want to be visible in a folder. Then disable the top, left, and bottom sections of the touch screen. Disable the left to prevent a swipe from moving them back to the main album photo listing.

After you setup Guided Access, it will remember your settings. If you just want to show one picture, just disable touch altogether.

Comment: This answer has been very useful.  Sadly, it's now out of date.  )e.g. "Triple-click the home button" doesn't apply anymore as there is no home button!)      Any updates greatly appreciated!!